# Consolidating records on Crystal 11?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I am trying to consolidate the records on my report to show only unique lanes (Shipper State and Destination State).

My data is currently grouped by customer group and then customers that fall within each group.

Ideally I would like my data to fit in this format.

```
LANE          ACCEPTED         Total            Percentage
Customer Group: Fruits
Customer: Apple 
GA-TN            1               2                   50%
GA-FL            2               3                   66%
Customer: Bannana
GA-TN            2               4                   50%
Total            5               9                   55%
```

Currently my data looks like the image attached.

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: explain something what you have done? you expect people to understand everthing with just seeing screenshot?

Comment: @siva essentially i have a running total field by customer group, however i am attempting to have it so that it shows the total count by state to state individually by customer...

Comment: Really..couldn't understand your requirement and there is no relavance to the explanation provided and sample data

Comment: its okay I solved it, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

1) Consolidated the Lanes by creating it in Formula Field, followed by creating adding it to the Group